# Reemplazar un yield en php 5.3.3

Tags: php

Hola lo que sucede es que en el servidor que trabajo se encuentra la version de php 5.3.3 y pues por cuestiones mayores no podemos simplemente actualizar el php, y el codigo que utilizo para realizar una inserción en base de datos utiliza la función `yield` y solo esta disponible desde la 5.5, como puedo reemplazarla?

```
function filedata(){
$central = 'AVC05';
    $file = fopen("data_centrales/datos_".$central.".log", "r");
    if(!$file){
        echo "No se pudo abrir el archivo";
    } else {
        while(($line = fgets($file)) !== false){
            yield $line;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: añade tu código por favor, de otro modo es dificil poder ayudarte

Comment: @shadow listo men, gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solo tienes que almacenar los valores en un array y luego devolver ese array.

```
function filedata(){
    $central = 'AVC05';   
    $fi le = fopen("data_centrales/datos_".$central.".log", "r");
    if(!$file){
        echo "No se pudo abrir el archivo";
    } else {
        $lines = [];
        while(($line = fgets($file)) !== false){
            $lines[] = $line;
        }
        return $lines
    }
}
```

Comment: * verificar el uso de memoria, la magia de yield es retornar un iterable item por item. Si vuelca habrá que refactorizar el ciclo donde se hace la inserción.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo en el uso de memoria, pero no hay magia posible si la construcción no está disponible en la versión que están usando. No obstante, un array es un elemento iterable y estoy 100% seguro que no es necesario una refactorización del bucle donde se ejecuta la función.

Comment: refactorización de la inserción, no de la función. Si el archivo leído es muy grande va a explotar el array, el cual pareciera se usa para iterar en las inserciones. Por otro lado en este caso particular tal vez se pueda usar [`file`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) y evitar el while